# Set img src without knowing extension

Tags: php, html

So I have a few images in the server (public_html/img/profile_pictures/).

This is how I currently set the image:

```
echo "<img src='img/profile_pictures/main_photo.png'/>";
```

The main_photo can change each day, but if it changes to main_photo.jpg insted, it wont show (because the extension is hardcoded on that line(`.png`)). Is it possible to display the photo without knowing the extension for the image file?

Comment: You could look before with PHP from whith what  type-extension there exists a fild and only macke a echo for this.

Comment: You can give the file no extension at all if you can ensure that the server returns the image with the correct MIME type nonetheless.

Comment: You can also have PHP check the existence of either file and set the right extension in the HTML, or use a php script as "image" that just returns a redirect to either image.

Comment: The key point is how you can stably get the latest and correct URL of the image. How do you determine which one is correct if there is "a few images" in the folder?

Comment: @CherryDT So an image doesn't need to have an extension?

Comment: What the browser cares about is the MIME type returned in the `Content-Type` header (e.g. `image/png`), not how the URL looks (the concept of an extension doesn't exist in the URL anyway)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a PHP code, then try this. This code will look for `main_photo.*` inside your folder and automatically set the extension upon finding one.

Remember to set the path properly

```
<?php
$yourPhotoPath = "img/profile_pictures/";

foreach (glob($yourPhotoPath.'main_photo.*') as $filename) {

    $pathInfo = pathinfo($filename);
    $extension = $pathInfo['extension'];
    $fileName = chop($pathInfo['basename'], $extension);

    echo "<img src='".$yourPhotoPath.$fileName.$extension."'/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if a Photo isn't loaded, it's width and size is null.

Although I would advise you to write a class that checks and loads images, I get a feeling you want a simple solution. so, given by the premise that the photo is either

```
<img src='img/profile_pictures/main_photo.png'/>
```

or

```
<img src='img/profile_pictures/main_photo.jpg'/>
```

and that neither this path nor this filename ever changes and in the folder is only one picture,

**you could simply echo both.**

The img of the one that is empty will not be shown.
A better way was to write a class that loads your photo and checks if the photo is really there, like

```
$path = 'img/profile_pictures/main_photo.png';
if(!file_exists('img/profile_pictures/main_photo.png'))
{
     //use the jpg path
     $path = 'img/profile_pictures/main_photo.jpg';
}
```

You can ofc just inline this if case, but it's bad practise to intermix buisinesslogic and format logic, so I advice you to write a class for it.